# Towers of Hanoi with 4 towers

Tags: python, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

So far i know how to do the tower of Hanoi with 3 towers, but i have no idea on how to implement the  Frame Steward Algorithm for 4 towers.

this is how my current three tower function looks like.

```
def move_three_towers(n, from_tower, to_tower, spare_tower):
    if (n > 0):

        move_three_towers(n-1, from_tower, spare_tower, to_tower)
        print(from_tower, ' --> ', to_tower)
        move_three_towers(n-1, spare_tower, to_tower, from_tower)
```

i need help implementing n - k disks to another tower using 4 towers. for some 1 ≤ k < n

here is my attempt at the algorithm but it doesn't work, please help.

```
def move_four_towers(n, k = 0, from_tower, to_tower, spare_tower1, spare_tower2):
     if n == 1:
        print(from_tower, ' --> ', to_tower)
     if n > 1:
        move_four_towers(n - k, from_tower, spare_tower2, spare_tower1, to_tower)
        print(from_tower, ' --> ', to_tower)
        move_three_towers(k, from_tower, to_tower, spare_tower1)
        move_four_towers(n - k, spare_tower2, to_tower, spare_tower1, from_tower)
```

Comment: @kindall: the Frame Steward algorithm give a solution which is conjectured to be optimal in the number of moves. Yours is certainly not.

Comment: But i would like to optimize my solution to use the Frame Stewart Algorithm, ignoring a tower defeats the purpose of having 4 towers.

Comment: Well, think about what you'd use another tower for if solving the game by hand. Try it with 4 discs, first using 3 towers and then using 4. How could you use the fourth tower to solve it faster?

Comment: @kindall +1 I would have loved to turn that in (ignoring the 4th) when I was in college  and to see the look on my professor's face.

Comment: You have misunderstood Frame Steward. For a given n, you have to pick the optimal k -- it's not a parameter to the function. For 4 pegs, that k is n - round(sqrt(2n+1)) + 1.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia gives a nice description of the algorithm for `r` pegs and n disks:

> The algorithm can be described recursively:
>
> - For some `k`, `1 <= k < n`, transfer the top `k` disks to a single peg other than the start or destination pegs, taking `T(k,r)` moves.
> - Without disturbing the peg that now contains the top k disks, transfer the remaining `n-k` disks to the destination peg, using only the remaining `r-1` pegs, taking `T(n-k,r-1)` moves.
> - Finally, transfer the top `k` disks to the destination peg, taking `T(k,r)` moves.

Comment: I understand the algorithm and can do it manually, but what i am having trouble with is implementing it.

Comment: Well, using the above as a (pretty good) template, can you show us what you have?

Comment: I've edited the post, i still can't implement the algorithm correctly.